# Fullcalendar v2.3, setting timelineDay as default view

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar, scheduler

I use fullcalendar v.2.3 on my project and now I am trying to integrate the scheduler v.1.3.
I found some troubles on this, and I am not sure if this is because of versions or what.
Fullcalendar works, but I cannot group by resources, or have default view: timelineDay.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Brigitte you do realize scheduler basicly is fullcalendar with another functionality. Why are you trying to integrate it in the other calendar ?

Comment: I just added the scheduler.js and scheduler.css files and included them to my layout. But when I use scheduler functionalities like grouping by dates and resources or timelineDay view, they don't work :(
I've been careful on ordering the scripts, but still have the problem.
Could you give me any advice? Thanks :)

Comment: Can you post some code or post a JSFiddle ?